# Create curve with svg as curve object (spline)

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, svg, curve-modifier

Disclaimer: am new to blender and 3D modeling.

I am modeling a candy cane in the shape of our company logo. Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBn3GQTSph4&ab_channel=blendera), i could create the same standard shape candy cane. However, when trying to replace the candy cane curve with our company logo (svg imported from illustrator), all kind of weird unexpected shapes occur. When loosely recreating our logo in blender with a new bezier curve, the curve behaves as expected (see screenshot). Is it possible to do this with an external curve (svg) and what might go wrong?

Image: left: rough shape candy cane working as expected. Middle: company logo svg. Right: huge, warped candy cane with curve modifier to logo svg

[image: left: rough shape candy cane working as expected. Middle: company logo svg. Right: huge, warped candy cane with curve modifier to logo svg]

Comment: Yes, you can use imported SVG curves. Check the imported curve for overlapping points or share your blend file for others to test.